# Python method-wrapper type?

Tags: types, python-3.x

What is the method-wrapper type in Python 3?  If I define a class like so:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val
```

And then do:

```
Foo(42).__eq__
```

I get:

```
<bound method Foo.__eq__ of <__main__.Foo object at 0x10121d0>>
```

But if I do (in Python **3** ):

```
Foo(42).__ne__
```

I get:

```
<method-wrapper '__ne__' of Foo object at 0x1073e50>
```

What is a "method-wrapper" type?

Edit: sorry to be more accurate: `class method-wrapper` is the type of `__ne__`, as if I do:

```
>>> type(Foo(42).__ne__)
<class 'method-wrapper'>
```

Whereas the type of `__eq__` is:

```
>>> type(Foo(42).__eq__)
<class 'method'>
```

Furthermore `method-wrapper` seems to be the type of any undefined magic method on a class (so `__le__`, `__repr__`, `__str__` etc if not explicitly defined will also have this type).

What I am interested in is how the `method-wrapper` class is used by Python.  Are all "default implementations" of methods on a class just instances of this type?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is because 'unbound methods' don't exist in Python 3.

> In Python 3000, the concept of unbound methods has been removed, and the expression "A.spam" returns a plain function object. It turned out that the restriction that the first argument had to be an instance of A was rarely helpful in diagnosing problems, and frequently an obstacle to advanced usages --- some have called it "duck typing self" which seems an appropriate name. 
>   [(Source)](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2009/02/first-class-everything.html)

In Python 2.x, we had bound methods and unbound methods. A bound method was bound to an object, meaning that when it was called, it passed the object instance as the first variable (`self`, normally). An unbound method was one where the function was a method, but without a instance it belonged to - it would throw an error if something other than an object instance was passed in to the method.

Now, in 3.x, this has been changed. Instead of bound/unbound methods, when you request a method of an object, it returns the function object, but wrapped in a wrapper function that passes the instance variable in. This way there is no need to make a distinction between bound and unbound methods - bound methods are wrapped, unbound are not.

To clarify the difference:

2.x:

```
a = A()
f = A.method # f is an unbound method - you must pass an instance of `A` in to it as the first argument.
f = a.method # f is a bound method, bound to the instance `a`.
```

3.x:

```
a = A()
f = A.method # f is a function
f = a.method # f is a wrapped function with it's first argument filled with `a`.
```

`a.method` can be thought of as:

```
def method-wrapper():
    A.method(a)
```

For more on this, check out Guido's blog - [the history of Python](http://python-history.blogspot.co.uk/2010/06/inside-story-on-new-style-classes.html).

Edit:

So, the reason this all applies is that, here, `__ne__()` has not been overridden - it's at a default state, which is an identity check, [implemented in C](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/0a9143d7b097/Objects/descrobject.c) (line 980ish). The wrapper is there to provide the method with the above functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, so what's a `method-wrapper` type then?  Is it just Python 3's equivalent to an unbound function?  But you call it the same way you would a regular wrapped function (like the `__ne__` example above), so I don't get it.

Comment: No, an unbound method doesn't exist in Python 3 - that's just a function. (Unbound methods stopped you passing in a first argument that wasn't the type of the class the method was from, but that was considered an artificial limit and removed). A wrapped-method is a bound method - it know what instance it belongs to and the method is wrapped to provide that instance.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't think my question has been answered: what is a `method-wrapper` type?  For both the `__eq__` and `__ne__` methods the types are different, but they both receive an implicit first argument.  Are you saying that a `method-wrapper` type method is one which is not aware of which instance it belongs to?  But if that's the case, then how does `someinst.__ne__(otherinst)` work (since it's bound to the `someinst` instance)?

Comment: @AdamParkin I added a little bit at the end, to try and make it more clear why this is relevant.

Comment: @Marcin Yes, but not in this situation due to the reasons described in the answer.

Comment: So, what is the difference between `__eq__` and `__ne__` which makes one `method` but the other `method-wrapper`?  This is the question, and most of this answer seems irrelevant to that question.

Answer (score 36):

It appears that the type `<method-wrapper ..>` is used by CPython for methods implemented in C code. Basically the type doesn't wrap another method. Instead it wraps a C-implemented function as a bound method. In this way `<method-wrapper>` is exactly like a `<bound-method>`  except that it is implemented in C.

In CPython there are two special types related to this.

- `<slot wrapper>` Which (at least) wraps a C-implemented function. Behaves like an `<unbound method>` in CPython 2 (at least sometimes) or a `<function>` in CPython 3
- `<method-wrapper>` Which wraps a C-implemented function as a bound method. Instances of this type have a `__self__` attribute__ which is used as first argument when it is called.

If you have a `<slot wrapper>` you bind it to an object with `__get__` to get a `<method-wrapper>`:

```
# returns a <slot_wrapper> on both CPython 2 and 3
sw = object.__getattribute__  

# returns a <method-wrapper>
bound_method = sw.__get__(object()) 

# In this case raises AttributeError since no "some_attribute" exists.
bound_method("some_attribute")
```

You can call `__get__` on any function-like object in Python to get a `<bound method>` or `<method-wrapper>`. Note `__get__` on both of these types will simply return self.

### Python 3

The type `object` in CPython 3 have C-implementations for both `__ne__` and `__eq__`, and any of the other comparison operators. Thus `object.__ne__` returns a `<slot wrapper>` for this operator. Likewise `object().__ne__` returns a `<method-wrapper>` which can be used to compare the this object.

Since you have not defined `__ne__` in your class you get a bound method (as `<method-wrapper>`) which is the C-implemented function for instance of object (included derived instances). My bet is that this C function will check if you have defined any `__eq__`, call this, and then *not* the result.

### Python 2 (not asked but answered)

Python 2 behaves significantly different here. Since we have the concept of unbound methods. which require that you call them with the proper first-argument type, both `<slot wrapper>` and `<method-wrapper>` have a `__objclass__` which is the type the first-argument must be an instance of.

More over: Python 2 does not have any implementations of comparisons operators for the `object` type. Thus `object.__ne__` is not a function to compare objects. Rather, interesting, the type `type` which is the metaclass of `object` does have a C-implemented `__ne__` operator. Thus you get a bound method from `object.__ne__` that will try to compare the type `object` with any other type (or object).

Thus `object().__ne__` will actually fail with an `AttributeError` since `object` does not define any such method. Given that `object() == object()` actually works (giving False), I would guess that CPython 2 have special-cases in the interpreter for comparison of objects.
Once more we see that CPython 3 have cleaned up some less-fortunate implementation details of Python 2.

Comment: Thanks! Are objects of `<slot wrapper>` and `<method-wrapper>` both callables and descriptors?

Comment: Both are callables, but only <slot wrapper> is a descriptor (ie. has a `__get__` method). This is unlike pure-python-3 code where `types.MethodType` is a descriptor as well. Thou that is probably just because on Python 2 `types.MethodType` represents both unbound and bound methods thus needing a `__get__` to let you bind a unbound method to an object.

Comment: Slot-wrapper and method-wrapper objects have `__objclass__` on Python 3 as well. Also, slot-wrapper and method-wrapper are only used for methods corresponding to C slots; there are a bunch of other C method types, most prominently method-descriptor and builtin-function-or-method, method-descriptor being used for methods like `list.append` and builtin-function-or-method being used for bound methods like `[].append` (and also for functions, like `max`).

Answer (score -1):

Below some testcode from my variable inspection routines. Defined class Tst, which has a `__str__` method. To find out if an instance of a class has either `__repr__` or `__str__` defined, you can test for `hasattr(obj.__str__, '__code__')`:

Example:

```
class Tst(object):
    """ Test base class.
    """
    cl_var = 15

    def __init__(self, in_var):
        self.ins_var = in_var

    def __str__(self):
        # Construct to build the classname ({self.__class__.__name__}).
        # so it works for subclass too.
        result = f"{self.__class__.__name__}"
        result += f"(cl_var: {self.__class__.cl_var}, ins_var: {self.ins_var})"
        return result

    def show(self):
        """ Test method
        """
        print(self.ins_var)


t5 = Tst(299)


print('\n\n----- repr() ------')
print(f"obj.repr(): {repr(t5)}")
print(f"obj.repr.class type: {type(t5.__repr__.__class__)}")
print(f"obj.repr.class.name: {t5.__repr__.__class__.__name__}")
print(f"obj.__repr__ has code: {hasattr(t5.__repr__, '__code__')}")

print('\n\n----- str() ------')
print(f"obj.str(): {str(t5)}")
print(f"obj.str.class type: {type(t5.__str__.__class__)}")
print(f"obj.str.class.name: {t5.__str__.__class__.__name__}")
print(f"obj.__str__ has code: {hasattr(t5.__str__, '__code__')}")
```

Returns:

```
----- repr() ------
obj.repr(): <__main__.Tst object at 0x107716198>
obj.repr.class type: <class 'type'>
obj.repr.class.name: method-wrapper
obj.__repr__ has code: False


----- str() ------
obj.str(): Tst(cl_var: 15, ins_var: 299)
obj.str.class type: <class 'type'>
obj.str.class.name: method
obj.__str__ has code: True
```

Since `__repr__` isn't defined on the class, it defaults to the `__repr__` on base-class `object` via the `method-wrapper` and gives a default output.
`__str__` is defined (and thus a method), so the test `hasattr(t5.__str__, '__code__')` results True.