# How to check if __str__ is implemented by an object

Tags: python

I want to dynamically implement `__str__` method on a object if the object doesn't already implement it.

I try using `hasattr(obj, '__str__')` it always returns me true as it picks it up from object class.

Is there a way to determine if an object actually implements `__str__` ?

I know I can use `inspect.getmembers(obj)` but I am searching for a more pythonic way

**EDIT**

```
class Employee(object):
def __init__(self, name, age, emp_code):
    self.name = name
    self.age  = age
    self.emp_code = emp_code
```

**Test**

```
e = Employee("A", 23, "E1")
print hasattr(e, '__str__')
>> True
```

I want a check that returns `False` instead of picking up the method inherited from `object`.

Comment: I already tried using hasattr for '__str__' however it always returns true. The other thing is, if I use hasattr for '__eq__' it works fine

Comment: Is it sufficient to check if `obj.__str__ != object.__str__`?

Comment: Do you want this to work for any inherited `__str__` method? What if the method isn't from `object`, but some other class on the inheritance chain?

Comment: I want to check only for the immediate class not the inherited ones

Comment: "dynamically implement `__str__`" smells highly suspicious.  how/why are you doing this?

Comment: I hope you're aware that you can't monkeypatch special methods onto existing objects; Python won't check the instance's dict for special method lookup.

Comment: Alas, monkey patching `__str__` doesn't work.

Comment: dynamic str would be used in a test case, i don't want the original objects to implement it, but when using test case want to print out some useful logging

Comment: why don't you just implement `__repr__` normally then?  that's basically what it's for

Comment: `__repr__` is supposed to provide unambiguous representation for the objects, also when one calls str(list) internally __repr__ is called. I don't want to accidentally start print some logs which are not desirable.

Comment: `__repr__` is only supposed to provide whatever's useful to a developer.  and you can then just define `__str__` to raise a `TypeError`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Since what you want to check is if it has a `__str__` implementation that is *not* the default `object.__str__`. Therefore, you can do this:

```
Foo.__str__ is not object.__str__
```

To check with instantiated objects you need to check on the class:

```
type(f).__str__ is not object.__str__
```

This will also work even if Foo doesn't implement `__str__` directly, but inherited it from another class than `object`, which seems to be what you want.

Comment: Good example use case of `is` instead of `==` also. EDIT: The OP wants something that doesn't look for inherited methods at all.

Comment: need `type(f).__dict__['__str__']` to circumvent inheritance.  mmm, dunders.

Comment: Oddly, it even works when you do `f = Foo(); f.__str__ = lambda: 'sneaky'` because `str(f)` does not call `f.__str__()` (!).

Comment: Though it still doesn't answer why `hasattr(obj, '__eq__')` works fine and `hasattr(obj, '__str__')` fails

Comment: @torek special methods are only ever checked on the class, yeah.

Comment: @Bhushan because `object` implements `__str__` and not `__eq__`  :)

Comment: Apologies to Lennart, but how can I implement `__str__` dynamically ? When I do setattr(obj, lambda x:"new str") it keeps calling the object class toString()

Comment: you **cannot** implement special methods on objects.  only on their classes.

Comment: Ahh got it.. setattr(obj.__class__, '__str__', lambda x: "new String")

Comment: @Bhushan: 1. You don't need setattr. Just set the attribute. 2. Why not just implement the method on the class in the first place?

Comment: @Eevee: Yet `object.__eq__` gets you a thing.  It just gets you a 'method-wrapper ...' instead of a 'slot wrapper ...' (in Python2; in Python3 it gets you a slot-wrapper).  In fact, in Python3, `hasattr(f, '__eq__')` is always true when `f` is an instance of a class derived from object.  See also [Python method-wrapper type?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10401935/1256452)

Comment: @LennartRegebro I am doing it for a test utility which will print string representation if there isn't already one. Since the code is already in prod, I don't want people to implement str if it is not required for business logic

Comment: @Bhushan: It would probably be better not to do str() on objects in that case, but make your own method.

Comment: Python 2's `object.__eq__` is not a method on the `object` _class_.  it comes from `type`, of which `object` is an instance.  Python 3 actually introduced an `__eq__` on the class.  i assume this mess is due to the legacy of `__cmp__` and the general wacky default sorting in py2

Comment: @LennartRegebro Ohh yes, I can do it that way. Thanks for correcting

Answer (score 1):

Any object inheriting from the `object` base will have a `__str__` method, so testing if it exists is negligible.

You could store a flag attribute on the object, and test for that instead:

```
if not getattr(obj, 'has_str_override_flag'):
    override_str_here(obj)
    setattr(obj, 'has_str_override_flag', True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well in you object there is __dict__ that contains all the methods and variables that the object has. You can check if a given object has __str__() method implemented by

```
'__str__' in Employee.__dict__
```

or

```
'__str__' in vars(Employee)
```

There is no difference between vars() and __dict__, just vars() is more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that built-in types rely on `object.__str__` to do their (smart) formatting. I really only wanted to eliminate useless strings like `<__main__.Foo object at 0x10299d390>` and still have dict and other types printed properly. My solution:

```py
objre = re.compile(r"<.* object at 0x[0-9a-f]+>")
if objre.fullmatch(str(obj)):
    # Do smarter formatting
```

This won't catch default formatting of modules, functions etc, for which source code could be shown instead via `inspect.getsource()`, but I am not displaying them in my variable inspector anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use type(e).__dict__.get(method_name) to avoid KeyError if method_name not exists in class when using type(e).__dict__[method_name]

```
e = Employee("A", 23, "E1")
if type(e).__dict__.get('__str__'):
    print('__str__ implemented')
else:
    print('__str__ not implemented')
```