# Inspect.getsourcelines(None.__str__) throws confusing TypeError

Tags: python

Today one of my co-workers found the interesting case of

```
str(None)
'None'
```

So Naturally I wanted to see how None is defined

```
inspect.getsourcelines(None.__str__)
TypeError: <method-wrapper '__str__' of NoneType object at 0x91a870> is not a module, class, method, function, traceback, frame, or code object
```

Which probably isn't surprising since None's most likely defined in `C`. But that brings up the interesting question, if `None.__str__` isn't a module, class, method, etc what is it?

Comment: Was that Python 2.7?

Comment: Tested on both 2.7 and 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what is it?

It is a very good question.

```
>>> type(None.__str__)
<type 'method-wrapper'>
>>> None.__str__.__class__
<type 'method-wrapper'>
>>> type(None.__str__.__call__)
<type 'method-wrapper'>
```

Now, what it is depends on [which version of python you use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10401935/python-method-wrapper-type), but it is definitely a method-wrapper.