# Why does CPython create multiple instances of the same method?

Tags: cpython

```
>>> (1).__str__!=(2).__str__
True
```

Is there any technical reason why they've been made seperate objects instead of refering to a single object? It seems like it would be more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you don't get the `__str__` function, but a method wrapper for it.

```
>>> x = (1).__str__
>>> type(x)
<class 'method-wrapper'>
>>> x()
'1'
>>> x.__self__
1

>>> x = (2).__str__
>>> x()
'2'
>>> x.__self__
2
```

A method wrapper is an object that keeps a reference to `self`. So it has to be different for every instance.

For more details, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10433975/3212865).